# How to split a group by query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

| Id 1 | Id 2 | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | AAA | 10 |
| 001 | AAA | 10 |
| 001 | AAA | 10 |
| 001 | AAA | 10 |
| 001 | AAA | 10 |
| 001 | AAA | 10 |
| 001 | AAA | 10 |
| 001 | AAA | 10 |
| 001 | AAA | 10 |
| 001 | AAA | 10 |

If I do a select query like

```sql
SELECT id1,id2,sum(amount),count(*) from table group by id1,id2;
```

I get the answer like;

```
001 |AAA |100 |10
```

What I want to do is split this into two aggregates, so that the first 8 rows will have one aggregate sum and the next 2 should have the sum of next two rows [*8 is the cut off*].

For example, the answer should be like:

```
001 |AAA |80  |8
001 |AAA |20  |2
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

As mentioned in comments, the order of 8 rows+2 rows doesn't matter just that the records in both batches be mutually exclusive. Thanks @SadlyFullStack for the answer!

Comment: How do you decide the cutoff?

Comment: _"so that first 8 rows"_ - Whenever you say "the first" or "the last" then it means you **need** an `ORDER BY` being applied to the data, otherwise the terms "first" and "last" have no meaning; but you haven't told us how you intend to sort the data before picking the first 8 rows.

Comment: its a previously decided value in product.

Comment: You actually have 12 rows as well

Comment: @SadlyFullStack ,Yes if I have 16 rows ,it will have to be 8+8, the order doesnt matter.Just need to be sure that a row added in one batch is not to be added in another.

Comment: The purpose of this is => product have to create a counter part insert for every differntt combination of id1 and id2 OR every 8 records if the id1 and id2 are same for morethan 8 records.

Comment: in this example i have to create two counterpart transaction inserts (one with amount 80 and another with amount 20)

Comment: "...so that first 8 rows..." - In relational tables the rows don't have inherent ordering. There's no such thing as a first row, second row, or last row. The question doesn't make sense as asked. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since order doesn't matter, we can use `ceil` and `row_number` with a null order clause in a CTE to flag every 8 rows with a number. Then, we have another query to aggregate those based on the group number we created:

```
with grouped as
(
    select tbl.*
        , ceil(row_number() over (order by null) / 8) grp_num
    from tbl
)
select id1
    , id2
    , sum(amount)
    , count(*)
from grouped
group by id1, id2, grp_num
```